# How do I remove these wall mount faucet handles for my bathtub that have no screws?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, bathtub, replacement

I want to update these faucet handles for my bathtub but I cannot seem to figure out how to remove them.

There are no set screws. I think they’re made by Kingston brass. I don’t want to start pulling on  it.

I’m scared to destroy what’s in the background.

Can anyone help me ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You would pop the metal cover off the top.  Use a jeweler fine flat blade screwdriver to work the edge of the metal cover.

Comment: I would try this also the chrome purse probably snaps in at the brass joint where the slight corrosion is.

Comment: @EdBeal you might have to define "purse" in this context. I'm thinking woman's hand bag, and I'm not seeing how that relates...;)

Comment: Spell checker I guess piece not purse thanks+